# Sorting only a part of object/array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I've been struggling around this for a while now and can't seem to get the right algorithm.

What I want is to sort this:

```
$variable = '{
    "0": {
            "id": "0",
            "code": "main_colour",
            "label": "Main Colour",
            "options": [{
                "id": "825",
                "label": "White",
                "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
            }, {
                "id": "840",
                "label": "Cream",
                "products": ["3", "4", "5"]
            }],
            "position": "0"
        },
    "2": {
           "id": "0",
            "code": "size",
            "label": "Size",
            "options": [{
                "id": "825",
                "label": "S",
                "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
            }, {
                "id": "840",
                "label": "M",
                "products": ["3", "4", "5"]
            }],
            "position": "0"
        }
}';
```

And the output would be

```
$variable = '{
        "0": {
                "id": "0",
                "code": "main_colour",
                "label": "Main Colour",
                "options": [{
                    "id": "840",
                    "label": "Cream",
                    "products": ["3", "4", "5"]
                },{
                    "id": "825",
                    "label": "White",
                    "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
                }],
                "position": "0"
            },
        "2": {
               "id": "0",
                "code": "size",
                "label": "Size",
                "options": [{
                    "id": "840",
                    "label": "M",
                    "products": ["3", "4", "5"]
                }, {
                    "id": "825",
                    "label": "S",
                    "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
                }],
                "position": "0"
            }
    }';
```

So basically it should be sorted using the label inside the "options" without affecting the other fields. I've been trying usort and tried different algorithms but to no avail.

Current code that sorts only the outside "label" and not the inner label:

```
function optionsSort($a, $b) {
return strcmp($a['options'][0]['label'], $b['options'][0]['options']['label']);
}
usort($variable, "optionsSort"));
```

Comment: Show your code __please__

Comment: The order of your resource or object shouldn't make much difference to be honest. What is the issue with the order of the first object? And why are you unable to work with it as is?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
// your array
$variable = '{
    "0": {
            "id": "0",
            "code": "main_colour",
            "label": "Main Colour",
            "options": [{
                "id": "825",
                "label": "White",
                "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
            }, {
                "id": "840",
                "label": "Cream",
                "products": ["3", "4", "5"]
            }],
            "position": "0"
        },
    "2": {
           "id": "0",
            "code": "size",
            "label": "Size",
            "options": [{
                "id": "825",
                "label": "S",
                "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
            }, {
                "id": "840",
                "label": "M",
                "products": ["3", "4", "5"]
            }],
            "position": "0"
        }
}';

$a = json_decode($variable);
foreach ($a as $item) {
    // sorting function
    usort($item->options, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a->label, $b->label); });
}
```